# French language pack installed, but no French dictionary available, Firefox 108.0.1 (64 bits)

Tags: firefox, language-support

- Firefox 108.0.1 (64 bits)
- French language pack installed (see below picture)

[image]

When I right click on a *textarea*, I shoud have 'French dict', but there's nothing.

[image]

**What I missed to have French dictionary ?**

```
$ dpkg -l | grep firefox
ii  firefox                                       108.0.1+linuxmint1+vanessa                 amd64        The Firefox web browser
ii  firefox-locale-en                             108.0.1+linuxmint1+vanessa                 amd64        English language packs for Firefox
ii  firefox-locale-fr                             108.0.1+linuxmint1+vanessa                 amd64        French language packs for Firefox
```

```
$ echo $LANG
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not included in the Firefox language packs. This is a page which shows both:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/language-tools/

Comment: I already clicked on my French pack. Even more than 3 times (remove/install). No cigar

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek: Then maybe try the "French spelling dictionary".

Comment: That's it, I think they changed the way to use packs, before that was working. Thanks !